# Insertion not happening in aws database using knex query builder

Tags: mysql, node.js, amazon-web-services, knex.js

I am trying to insert into database which is basically on AWS. Earlier data insertion was happening, but now I am getting **success** as undefined. This one is not throwing error nor even sending any callback object.

```
function insertFlightData(dataArray){
  return database('flight_info')
  .insert(dataArray)
  .then(function(success){
    console.log(success); //success is undefined
    return logger.info('Successful data insertion');
  }).catch(function (err){
    logger.error(err);
    return err;
  });
}
```

I am using **knex** query builder (v^0.11.7). Below is code sample for creating connection using knex

```
const knex = require('knex')({
  client: config('DB_DILECT'),
  connection: {
    host     : config('DB_HOST'),
    user     : config('DB_USER'),
    password : config('DB_PASSWORD'),
    database : config('DB_DATABASE')
  },
  pool: {
    min: 0,
    max: 7
  }
});

module.exports = knex;
```

Select query is working perfectly fine, only insertion is creating issue.
When I used mysql workbench to check insert query in aws database, it worked. But from code, insertion is not happening.

Below is select query which is working

```
const database = require('../../db/database.js');
function selectAllSource(instanceNo){
  return database.select()
  .table('airport_info')
  .where('AwsInstanceNo', instanceNo)
  .then(function(rows){
    settings.source = rows;
    Object.freeze(settings.source);
    return rows.length;
  });
}
```

Comment: if this was working before, can you revert your code to see what has changed. This looks pretty straight forward so I would assume that the error is outside of the scope you have described. Can you access that database with write permissions manually? Can you show how you are doing the select query to give us more info?

Comment: This one is the original code that was working before, no code changes so far. Regarding database write permission, I have that, and it's working perfectly fine inside mysql workbench.